# Read stdin into R

Tags: r

I have a file that is structured like this:

```
123

Jhon: NewYork, Boston, gainesville

Mike: LosAngeles

Almudena: Baltimore, SanDiego, Austin, Memphis

Anna: Washington, Oklahoma, Nashville, Denver, Phenix, Tucson

...
```

And so on until 123 names and up to 50 cities per person. I want to read the file into a usable table in R, such as for example, a table with the 123 rows and 51 columns (name + 50 cities maximum). The ideal situation would be for the table to have blank spaces where there are no cities (for example, the row corresponding to a person that has only been in two cities in the US would have a 48 blank spaces.)

Another, more useful option would also be a two column table (or matrix) with two columns in the form of

```
Name City
Jhon NewYork
Jhon Boston
Jhon gainesville
Mike LosAngeles
...
```

Comment: BTW: IMHO that has nothing to do with *stdin*. Why do you tagged it as *stdin*?

Comment: Hi, because I was told "here you have data in stdin format", that was all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure whether there a function available. But it is not too hard to write an importer for this file:

```
ll <- readLines("input.txt")

## keep only lines with "name: cities"
ll <- ll[grep(":", ll)]

## split at ":" to divide in name and cities
s <- strsplit(ll, ":")

## split by "," to divide cities
s <- lapply(s, function(x) {
  return(cbind(x[1], strsplit(x[2], ",")[[1]]))
})

## bind list of matrices to one matrix
m <- do.call(rbind, s)

## remove whitespace in front of the cities
m[, 2] <- gsub("^\\s+", "", m[, 2])
m

#      [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] "Jhon"     "NewYork"
# [2,] "Jhon"     "Boston"
# [3,] "Jhon"     "gainesville"
# [4,] "Mike"     "LosAngeles"
# [5,] "Almudena" "Baltimore"
# [6,] "Almudena" "SanDiego"
# [7,] "Almudena" "Austin"
# [8,] "Almudena" "Memphis"
# [9,] "Anna"     "Washington"
#[10,] "Anna"     "Oklahoma"
#[11,] "Anna"     "Nashville"
#[12,] "Anna"     "Denver"
#[13,] "Anna"     "Phenix"
#[14,] "Anna"     "Tucson"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this today and found this old thread on a search. Below is how I approached this with tidyverse.

For tab-delimited: `readLines("input.txt") %>% read_tsv`

For comma-delimited: `readLines("input.txt") %>% read_csv`